# Выводит 414 ошибок при создании проекта С++

Tags: c++

Весьма неожиданная проблема. При открытии или создании нового проекта выдаёт то, что изображено на скриншоте.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно VS не получает доступ к стандартным библиотекам. Проверьте установлен ли Windows SDK. Если же таковой есть, рекомендую переустановку Visual Studio. 
Если не помогло, то удаляем Visual Studio таким способом -  файл InstallCleanup.exe (по умолчанию C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe) запустить его  с ключом "-f" (если требуется полное удаление продукта насовсем). Последний вариант может затронуть компоненты, используемые другими инсталляцими Visual Studio. 
После устанавливаем заново.
Возможно эта проблема линковки в настройках программы но тут я помочь не могу.